# Magento Import - FK Integrity Constraint Violation

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm progmatically importing products into Magento 1.7.0.2 from an XML feed.

The script has run fine for the best part of a week, but now I'm getting the error shown below when products are saving.

How serious is this error, what can cause it?

I've tried reindexing everything and truncating a bunch of tables, the error seems to persist.

The Error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '51-1' for key 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID'
```

Import php (sample):

```
$sProduct = $this->_productModel;       
$sProduct->setTypeId($this->_productTypeSimple)
  ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
  ->setStatus($this->_productStatusDisabled)
  ->setVisibility($this->_productVisibilityNotVisible)
  ->setTaxClassId(2) //Taxable Good
  ->setAttributeSetId(XML_FEED_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET)
  ->setSku($arrayProductData['ProductSKU']) 
  ->setName($arrayProductData['ProductName'])
  ->setShortDescription($arrayProductData['ProductShortDescription'])
  ->setDescription($arrayProductData['ProductLongDescription'])
  ->setPrice(sprintf("%0.2f", $arrayProductData['ProductPrice']))   
  ->setRRP(sprintf("%0.2f", $arrayProductData['ProductPrice'])) 
  ->setWeight(0)    
  ->setCategoryIds($arrayProductData['ProductCategories'])
  ->setUrlKey(str_replace(array(" ","'","&"),"-",$arrayProductData['ProductName']) . "-" . $arrayProductData['ProductSKU']);

$sProduct->setStockData(
  array( 
    'use_config_manage_stock' => 1,
    'is_in_stock' =>1, 
    'qty' => $arrayProductData['ProductStockQty'] 
  )
);

$sProduct->setMetaTitle($arrayProductData['ProductName'])
->setMetaDescription(str_replace("<<THE_PRODUCT>>",$arrayProductData['ProductName'], DEFAULT_META_DESC));           

if(isset($arrayProductData['ProductSize'])) {
  $sProduct->setData("sizes", $arrayProductData['ProductSize']);
}

if(isset($arrayProductData['ProductColour'])) {
  $sProduct->setData("color", $arrayProductData['ProductColour']);
}
try {
  $sProduct->save();            
}
catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

As the error show

UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID

There is duplicate entry in DB table ( cataloginventory_stock_item ) for the same  product_id / stock_id

This could happen for different reasons

You can solve this by setting the ID of the product manually before save so it won't conflict get the last product ID and increment it.

or delete the row related to this new product from the table before save

Answer (score 0):

Further down the script I was creating configurable products based on certain criteria.

For reasons I've not yet uncovered the SKU of this configurable product doesn't appear to be unique, causing the issue above.

Thanks anyway Meabed.